# How to convert "stringWithFormat" to Java?

Tags: java, objective-c, string-formatting

I need the equivalent java code for the below statement:

```
param1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", (param2 - param3)];
```

where param1 is a string, param2 a double and param3 a float

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `String.format("%f", param2 - param3)` (which is closer to the original code) or `String.valueOf(param2 - param3)` (which is simpler).

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(String.valueOf(param2 - param3));